# Callling method from another class + sorting

Tags: java, sorting, methods

I am working on a program where I have to call a method that prompts the user to enter data from another class. This program should print the name, age, address, and  gender  of customers. However, I am having problem to call a method for inputting each customer information.

Also, I have to create a method that  sort  the ages of customers in ascending order. So the program prints out all info based on the order of age from the (youngest customer) to the (oldest one). I am not sure how to create a method that will only sort the ages of customers without sorting the name, address, and gender. I would really appreciate any feedback or comments!

This is what I have so far.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Customer1 {
        public  static void main(String [] args){

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x;

        System.out.print("Total number of customers: ");
        x = input.nextInt();

        Customer [] person = new Customer[x];


        System.out.println("Name" + "     " + "Age"+ "       " + "Address" +  "     " + "Gender");

        for(int i = 0; i < person.length; i++){
            System.out.println(person.toString());
        }


        }
}



class Customer{

        String name;
        int age;
        String address;
        String gender;

        public Customer(String newName, int newAge, String newAddress, String newGender){
            name = newName;
            age = newAge;
            address = newAddress;
            gender = newGender;

        }

        public void data(Customer [] person){

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            for(int i = 0; i < person.length; i++){

                System.out.print("Name: ");
                name= input.toString();

                System.out.print("Age: ");
                age = input.nextInt();

                System.out.print("Address: ");
                address= input.toString();

                System.out.print("Gender: ");
                gender = input.toString();


            }
        }

        /*This is the "uncompleted" method that I tried to create in order to sort  the ages of customers.
         But I don't know how to use it in  order to sort only the ages*/
        public void sort(Customer [] person){

          double temp;
          for(int a = 0; a < (person.length - 1); a++){

                    for( int b = (a + 1); b < person.length; b++){
                            if(person[a] > person[b]){

                                    temp = person[a];
                                    person[a] = person[b];
                                    person[b] = temp;

                            }


                    }


            }


        }

        public String toString(){

            String result;
            result = name + "       " + age + "           " +  address +  "       " + gender;
            return result;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the below code which might solve this question .. I have included the methods suggested in the previous replies and created this program ..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ReadSortCustomerData {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
    int numberOfCustomers;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the total number of customers: ");
    numberOfCustomers = input.nextInt();

    CustomerData [] customer = new CustomerData[numberOfCustomers];

    for(int countCustomer=0 ; countCustomer < numberOfCustomers; countCustomer++) {

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the"+(countCustomer+1)+"customer");
        customer[countCustomer].setName(input.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the age of the"+(countCustomer+1)+"customer");
        customer[countCustomer].setAge(input.nextInt());
        System.out.println("Enter the gender of the"+(countCustomer+1)+"customer");
        customer[countCustomer].setGender(input.next());
        System.out.println("Enter the address of the"+(countCustomer+1)+"customer");
        customer[countCustomer].setGender(input.next());
    }


  }

    public CustomerData[] sortCustomerData(CustomerData[] customers) {

        for (int i=0;i<customers.length;i++) {

            for(int j=i+1;j<customers.length;j++) {

                if(ageCompare(customers[i], customers[j])==1) {
                    CustomerData tempCustomer = new CustomerData();
                    tempCustomer = customers[i];
                    customers[i] = customers[j];
                    customers[j] = tempCustomer;
                }

                }
            }

        return customers;
    }

    public int ageCompare(CustomerData a, CustomerData b)
    {
        return a.getAge() < b.getAge() ? -1 : a.getAge() == b.getAge() ? 0 : 1;
    }
}




import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class CustomerData {

    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String address;
    private String gender;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

}
```

This might need some tweaking during the run time but it should give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to rethink a little bit your code and take a look at the following tips

**Using Comparator or Comparable interfaces**

These interfaces helps you out with the sorting of your collections, lists and etc, i.e, the [Comparator interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) allows you to impose ordering to your collection with a hand from Collections.sort and Arrays.sort operations.

You must define the implementation of you Comparator, based on you target class(Person), then define the ordering by any field you want:

```
class PersonSort implements Comparator<Person>{

@Override
public int compare(Person p1, Person p2) {
    return p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();
}}
```

Then you are allowed to force its ordering via Arrays.sort(T[], Comparator):

```
Arrays.sort(yourArray, new PersonSort());
```

I also recommend you to take a look at [Oracle's Collection Framework Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). You will find information over ordering, implementations and etc.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Getting the data that you require**

Currently in your `Customer1` class you're accepting an x amount of customers provided from user input. Following which you create an array for x `Customer` objects. You do not currently populate the array with any data.

```
Customer[] person = new Customer[x];
```

After this line you could then do a for loop with the following:

```
        String name;
        int age;
        String address;
        String gender;
        for( int i = 0; i < person.length; i++ )
        {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            name = input.next();

            System.out.print("Age: ");
            age = input.nextInt();

            System.out.print("Address: ");
            address= input.next();

            System.out.print("Gender: ");
            gender = input.next();

            person[i] = new Customer( name, age, address, gender );
        }
```

A cavaet must be observed in your code, you've put `input.toString()`. This will give you a string representation of your scanner, not the input. `input.next()` will give you next input as a string.

**2.Sorting**

I would advise looking at the [comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) documentation. Have a comparator object that implements comparator with `Customer` as the type parameter. Override the compare to check against each `Customer` object's age.

Example would be:

```
class CustomerComparator implements Comparator<Customer>
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer a, Customer b)
    {
        return a.age < b.age ? -1 : a.age == b.age ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

You should look into making the variables `name`, `age`, `address` `gender` private and using `getX()` methods (getters/setters).

Comment: So I have to create (getters/setters) for all the variables?